# Data validation in Excel

Tags: excel

Currently, I am engaged in module of importing excel file using c#.But before importing excel file, client entered the data into excel file in different column header.So, I have to make validation in client's entered data such as blank of cell, string, decimal,etc but i am not in rush of using vba. So, Is there any way(except vba) to do validation in excel??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at `Data > Validation...` in menu bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the Data tab, use the Data Validation drop-down menu.

[image: Preview]